# What is an if statement technically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is an if statement an expression or simply a statement? And can someone define the two? I've heard it as a conditional expression, but that just confuses me as to why it's generally called an if statement rather than an expression.

Comment: An if statement *is a statement*. A conditional expression (which is not the same thing) is an *expression*. Hence the names...

Comment: An `if statement` is used with a `conditional expression`

Comment: @byxor No, that is wrong.

Comment: @byxor It is still wrong. An if-statement doesn't evaluate to anything, it controls the flow of the program. A conditional expression *evaluates to something*, that is why it is an *expression*.

Comment: "An if-statement doesn't evaluate to anything", I agree, I never said it did. You can't have an if statement without a conditional expression, but you can have a conditional expression without an if statement. That's all I was getting across.

Comment: Names don't need to make sense. It's called an if statement simply because it has been called so for a long time. It certainly isn't an expression, the conditional part being evaluated within the if statment may be an expression (for example True) but the statment itself acts on that expression to branch the flow the logic flow to the true code path and false code path.

Comment: @byxor no, you are using those terms incorrectly. You can *definitely have an if-statement without a conditional expression*. They are two separate things. They simply share the `if` token in their syntax. But one is a statement, the other is an expression. Consider, the `if` statement has existed for as long as Python existed, the conditional expression didn't exist until Python 2.5, and it only so happens that it uses the `if` token. There were other [proposals for the syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression-in-Python/answer/Anders-Kaseorg?srid=p3SU hope this help.

Comment: @SuperTetelman they don't need to make sense, but in this case, they do and are totally consistent with the way these terms are used in computer science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two different things. Python code is made up of statements. Statements *can* contain expressions, and expressions produce a result. Expressions can be composed out of more expressions, expressions can't contain statements.

There is such a thing as an [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement). An `if` statement controls the flow of the program (different suites are executed based on the outcome of a test expression):

```
if sometest:
    # execute if sometest is true
elif someothertest:
    # execute if sometest was false and someothertest is true
else:
    # execut if both sometest and someothertest are false
```

There is also such a thing as a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions); this produces a result, based on the constituent components (one of two expressions contained within is evaluated and its result returned, based on the condition expression in the middle):

```
# will produce either the outcome of true_expression or false_expression
true_expression if sometest else false_expression
```

These two concepts are distinct; one is a statement (a top-level component of the language), the other an expression (so produces a result). They have closely related syntax (both use `if` as a keyword, the keyword `else` is required in a conditional expression, optional in an `if` statement), both evaluate a condition (`if` statements can evaluate more), but that's where their relationship ends.

Or, to emphasise the differences some more:

- The suites in an `if` statement can hold more statements. You can use an `if` statement to pick between two function definitions, or two classes, or choosing what to import. You can't do that in an expression, because an expression can't contain a statement.
- A conditional expression can be part of a larger expression, while you can't put statements in an expression. So you can use a conditional expression to fine-tune an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Example of an if statement

```
if x > 6:
    a = 3
else:
    a = 4
```

Example of a conditional expression: the part right from the =

```
a = 3 if x > 6 else 4
```

These are two completely different language constructs, but here they achieve the same.

The conditional expression here is more compact than the if-statement.
But if conditional expressions get more complicated, they tend to become hard to read and debug, e.g.:

```
    x = (
            self.intervalWidthNode.old + self.parent.phaseModule.deltaXyNode.new [0] / self.parent.phaseModule.pixelsPerUnitXyNode.new [0]
        if (
            isinstance (self.imageFactoryNode.new, mk.AllColorsImageFactory) and
            self.parent.phaseModule.deltaXyNode.triggered and
            self.parent.phaseModule.inTransferAreaXyNode.new == (False, False)
        ) else
            self.imageFactoryNode.new.intervalWidth
        if (
            isinstance (self.imageFactoryNode.new, mk.AllColorsImageFactory) and
            self.imageFactoryNode.touched
        ) else
            self.intervalWidthNode.old
    )
```

Comment: No, they don't achieve the same. They both test a condition, but a statement alters program flow, an expression produces a value. That's a big difference! Statements don't produce values, expressions don't alter flow.

Comment: I meant that in this particular example, functionally they achieve the same. But indeed the difference you mention is the crux of the matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters while I agree that could come across more clearly in this answer, I believe what was being said is that both examples have the same effect *on `a`*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But you can't use a conditional expression to pick between statements to be executed, for example, nor can you use an `if` statement inside an expression. That Jacques added an assignment statement to both examples in my mind muddies the waters more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I hoped this would be clear: "Example of a conditional expression: the part right from the =". It seems somewhat artificial to me to use an expression without assigning the result to anything, or e.g. use it as a parameter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I agree that it could be more clear, but I think Jacques understands this distinction. Probably, yes, this example just sort of muddies the water...

Comment: Of course the matter is very complicated. Statements and expressions may be different in Python, but e.g. in C++ there are "expression statements". And by using functions with side effects one can make a conditional expression conditionally execute code. But its agreed those things don't help the OP. Reason for me to add the assignment is to make clear that in some situations one can choose between a if-statements and a  conditional expression. I would choose a conditional expression only in a simple situation. I believe it took some time before they were allowed in the language by the BDFL.